# Front end javascript testing using Require and Resharper

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, requirejs, frontend, durandal

So I've been trying to figure out how front end testing works (unit testing) but I am getting stuck on some point.

So I have my jasmine test set up as follows:

```
describe('Blabla', function () {

    it('returns true', function () {
        var people = require(["people"], function(ppl) {
            return ppl;
        });
        expect(people.getTitle()).toBe('People piolmjage');
    });
});
```

But running this gets me:

> TypeError: undefined is not a funtion

So obviously, people is undefined. So perhaps my callback comes in too late. But if I remove the callback I get following error:

```
it('returns true', function () {
    var people = require("people");
    expect(people.getTitle()).toBe('People piolmjage');
});
```

> Error: Module name "people" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

I figure there is something wrong in my setup...Anyone have any idea how to get this FE testing to work?

I did manage to get it to work from console and using `define` combined with phantomjs and the durandal test files but I need this to work outside of the console and hereby I cannot use this `define` because the test runner won't find my tests.

That's why I need to use the CommonJS was of getting the required viewmodels.

**people model**

```
define([],
function () {
    var getTitle = function() {
        return "hello";
    }

    var peopleViewModel = {
        title: 'People page',
        getTitle: getTitle
    };
    return peopleViewModel;
});
```

**UPDATE**

I got the code working but **not** with resharper. Following [this page from the durandal webpage](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Testing-With-PhantomJS-And-Jasmine.html).

But this gets me console output which is way to unstructured to actually read through.

I can however use the **define** keyword and then it works fine. So I assume it is the **require** keyword where I mess up something?

**UPDATE 2**

So I used fiddler to check what is going on. I also finally got it working (kinda...).

My testfile looks like this now:

```
///<reference path="../../Scripts/require.js"/>
///<reference path="../../test/lib/jasmine-2.1.3/jasmine.js"/>

///<reference path="../../App/viewmodels/people.js"/>

describe('Blabla', function () {
    it('require test', function (done) {
        require(['people'], function (people) {
            expect(people.title).toBe('People page');
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

And then I changed my `people` file:

```
define("people", ["bla"], function (bla) {
    return {
        title: 'People page',
        bla: bla
    };
});
```

As you can see here, I **name** my viewmodel to be `people`.
This works for the testrunner but he doesn't actually get any files through **requireJS** but only the reference paths. Also this does not fit my needs because the durandal models are **unnamed**.

Fiddler screenshot:

[image: Fiddler screenshot]

So basically he does not use **requireJS** to get the viewmodels and therefor I cannot just use the **require.config** initializer to get to my **viewmodels** folder and download every viewmodel using requireJS. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it working, took me like a day and a half.

Anyway I don't use resharper anymore, or it's test runner to be more precise.
**Chutzpah** is the one I turned to in the end. This too took me some research but I got it to the point where it includes everything as I want it to.

[Check this post for sure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657185/testing-javascript-with-chutzpah-and-requirejs)

Here is what I did:

My **people.js** looks like this:

```
define(['viewmodels/bla'], function (bla) {
    return {
        title: 'People page',
        bla: bla //testing dependencies on other viewmodels
    };
});
```

Then I also made a **bla.js**

```
define(function() {
    return {
       bla: "bla"
    };
});
```

And now for the tests:

```
describe('Blabla', function () {
it('require test', function (done) {
    require(['viewmodels/people'], function (people) {
        expect(people.title).toBe('People page');
        done();
    });
});

it('dependency on require test', function (done) {
    require(['viewmodels/people'], function (people) {
        console.log(people.bla);
        expect(people.bla.bla).toBe('bla');
        done();
    });
});
});
```

And then eventually, reading the answers on the link provided on top I had to create a **Chutzpah config file to create a test harnass**:

```
{
   "Framework": "jasmine",
   "TestHarnessReferenceMode": "AMD",
   "TestHarnessLocationMode": "SettingsFileAdjacent",
   "References" : [
       {"Path" : "../Scripts/require.js" }, 
       {"Path" : "requireConfig.js" }
   ],
   "Tests" : [
     {"Path": "specs"}
   ]
}
```

Now, running the tests with **Visual studio test runner** actually gets me everything I need and as you can see, I can now access all my **viewmodels** through require like so: `require(['viewmodels/whateverviewmodel'], function(whateverviewmodel){....})`

I hope this answer can get people on their way to testing your (Durandal)SPA using Jasmine and RequireJS.

I know my viewmodels in this answer, nor in the question itself, say much but this should get you an idea of how to go about all of this.

**Small Edit**

You can now also skip the callback mess with **require([]...** inside of the tests and **build your tests like you do your viewmodels with `define`**

```
define(['viewmodels/people'], function (people) {
    describe('Blabla', function () {
        it('require test', function () {
            expect(people.title).toBe('People page');
        });

        it('dependency on require test', function () {
            console.log(people.bla);
            expect(people.bla.bla).toBe('bla');
        });
    });
});
```

This gets you less indents and is more readable in itself.

Answer (score 0):

The `require` call provided by RequireJS is *inherently* asynchronous so you need to do something like this:

```
it('returns true', function (done) {
    require(["people"], function(people) {
        expect(people.getTitle()).toBe('People piolmjage');

        done(); // Signal that the test is done.
    });
});
```

The first attempt you show in your question cannot work. That's the classical "trying to return values synchronously form asynchronous code" mistake. The second attempt with `require("people")` does not work either because this `require` call is pseudo-synchronous and will work only if the module requested is *already* loaded. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23529707/1906307) for an explanation of how this pseudo-synchronous `require` works.

Comment: With your example I still get an error that `people` is undefined. **Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.** and in the console it says: getTitle() of undefined

Comment: Is your module actually returning a useful value at all? You don't show your module's code in your question.

Comment: So long as RequireJS is configured to load the code you show in your question when `"people"` is required (and not something else), then it should work. Also, did you copy-and-paste what I put in my answer? Trying to edit your original code to replicate what I have in my answer is error-prone.

Comment: I did edit my original code but to no success...I can't seem to find out why he does not include the "people" model correctlyµ